# Writing a Mathematical Formula in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have these tables: `users`, `comments`, `ratings`, and `items`

I would like to know if it is possible to write SQL query that basically does this:

user_id is in each table.  I'd like a SQL query to count each occurrence in each table (except `users` of course). BUT, I want some tables to carry more weight than the others.  Then I want to tally up a "score".

Here is an example:

user_id 5 occurs...
2 times in items;
5 times in comments;
11 times in ratings.

I want a formula/point system that totals something like this:

items 2 x 5 = 10;
comments 5 x 1 = 5;
ratings 11 x .5 = 5.5

TOTAL 21.5

This is what I have so far.....

```
SELECT u.users
     COUNT(*) r.user_id
     COUNT(*) c.user_id
     COUNT(*) i.user_id
FROM users as u
JOIN COMMENTS as c
     ON u.user_id = c_user_id
JOIN RATINGS as r
     ON r.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN ITEMS as i
     i.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    ????
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER by total DESC
```

I am not sure how to do the mathematical formula portion (if possible).  Or how to tally up a total.

**Final Code based on John Woo's Answer!**

```
$sql = mysql_query("
        SELECT  u.username,
    (a.totalCount * 5) +
    (b.totalCount) +
    (c.totalCount * .2) totalScore
    FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
            FROM items 
            GROUP BY user_id
        ) a ON a.user_id= u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
            FROM comments
            GROUP BY user_id
        ) b ON b.user_id= u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id) totalCount
            FROM ratings
            GROUP BY user_id
        ) c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
    ORDER BY totalScore DESC LIMIT 10;");
```

Comment: Be warned that count(*) is an integer, and all math operations will therefore use ints unless you `cast(value as float)` in your formulas.

Comment: I can easily adjust values so it uses integers instead of floats (if it means better performance and/or is the only option).

Comment: How about putting results in a temp table then applying the weighted system?

Comment: @JamesL.: What do you mean by *‘all math operations will therefore use ints unless you `cast(value as float)` in your formulas’* ? Are you implying that e.g. `count(*) * 0.5` would produce an `int` result?

Comment: That's the way it used to work.  Upon experimenting with SQLServer 2008, I see that Microsoft finally changed it...  Good news!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you,

```
SELECT  u.user_ID,
        (a.totalCount * 5) +
        (b.totalCount) +
        (c.totalCount * .2) totalScore
FROM    users u LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_ID, COUNT(user_ID) totalCount
                FROM items 
                GROUP BY user_ID
            ) a ON a.user_ID = u.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_ID, COUNT(user_ID) totalCount
                FROM comments
                GROUP BY user_ID
            ) b ON b.user_ID = u.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT user_ID, COUNT(user_ID) totalCount
                FROM ratings
                GROUP BY user_ID
            ) c ON c.user_ID = u.user_ID
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

but based on yur query above,thismay also work

```
SELECT  u.users
        (COUNT(*) * .5) +
        COUNT(*) +
        (COUNT(*) * 2) totalcore
FROM users as u
        LEFT JOIN COMMENTS as c
            ON u.user_id = c_user_id
        LEFT JOIN RATINGS as r
            ON r.user_id = u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN ITEMS as i
            ON i.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER by totalcore DESC
```

The only difference is by using `LEFT JOIN`. You will not use `INNER JOIN` in this situation because there are chances that `user_id` is not guaranteed to exists on every table.

Hope this makes sense

[image]

Comment: Hey this seems good, I had to clean up a few things, th eonly issue is, it says: `#1054 - Unknown column 'items' in 'group statement'`  I assume it will do that for comments and ratings as well. (this was based off your first suggestion).

Comment: @KickingLettuce sorry for the typo error. it should be `GROUP BY user_ID` try it again, i just updated the question.

Comment: Well, the bottom one works after cleaning up a few typos.  But it takes an incredible amount of time.  The top one gives me this error now: `#1052 - Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @KickingLettuce oops sorry typo again (*damn keyboard*). instead of `user_ID` change it to this `u.user_ID`

Comment: ok, I think I just saw that as well.. I'm on to something here. Give me a moment and I will add final code and mark you correct!

Comment: @KickingLettuce great! glad i was able to help you :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach:

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  SUM(s.weight) AS totalScore
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, 5.0 AS weight
    FROM items
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, 1.0
    FROM comments
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, 0.5
    FROM ratings
  ) s
  ON u.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY
  u.user_id
```

I.e. for every occurrence of every user in every table, a row with a specific weight is produced. The UNIONed set of weights is then joined to the `users` table for subsequent grouping and aggregating.